# Рендер карты Yandex API по координатам полей и населённого пункта

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api, yandex-places-api, yandex-maps-embed, yandex-static-maps-api

Есть код. Изначально не мой. Код рисует карту в нужной позиции с балуном (меткой). Функционал - когда перетаскиваешь карту, input получает координаты. Предоставляю примеры. Проблема в следующем. При указании координат в пустынной местности (грубо говоря в полях, просто копируем из яндекс карт) то карта рисуется вообще в другом месте. А если координаты берём из города то карта рисуется верно.

Тут код - https://inlnk.ru/Pmo8BE или тут (даю с ключом рабочим - дабы время не теряли).

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

    Адрес:
    <input type="text" id="address">

    Координаты:
    <input type="text" id="ypoint" class="form-input">

    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=f14114d6-4ebb-4087-b128-5d9d0454fd0e&lang&lang=ru_RU"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(init);
        function init() {
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                center: [47.222078, 39.720358],
                zoom: 10
            }, {
                searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
            });

            /* Начальный адрес метки */
            var address = [47.222078, 39.720358];

            ymaps.geocode(address).then(function(res) {
                var coord = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();

                var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coord, null, {
                    preset: 'islands#blueDotIcon',
                    draggable: true
                });

                /* Событие dragend - получение нового адреса */
                myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function(e){
                    var cord = e.get('target').geometry.getCoordinates();
                    $('#ypoint').val(cord);
                    ymaps.geocode(cord).then(function(res) {
                        var data = res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.getAll();
                        $('#address').val(data.text);
                    });
                });

                myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
                myMap.setCenter(coord, 15);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

❌ Возникает ошибка, пример 1 (поля).
Допустим мы ставим координаты для центра карта и самого балуна **45.573370, 42.975792**
По факту мы получаем карту с центром и меткой в другом месте (примерно) **45.781270891414714,42.65513599999969** что является не верным местом!

❌ Возникает ошибка, пример 2 (поля).
Допустим мы ставим координаты для центра карта и самого балуна **46.780526, 40.862630**
По факту мы получаем карту с центром и меткой в другом месте (примерно) **46.817641157742884,40.70974364418027** что является не верным местом!

✅ Работает верно, пример 3 (город).
Допустим мы ставим координаты для центра карта и самого балуна **47.222078, 39.720358**
По факту мы получаем карту с центром и меткой в другом месте (примерно) **47.22393713061284,39.72794710058595** что является - правильным местом.

> Грубо говоря закономерность - координаты взятые из полевой местности рисуют не верное отображение карты. Координаты взятые из городской местности - рисуют карту верно.

Уже писал в Yandex - сказали что всё норм у них рисуется. Уже несколько дней с этой проблемой вожусь, решился написать сюда.

Проверял в песочнице координаты из полей и городов - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage/ всё работает верно. Вернувшись к коду - наблюдается странная закономерность которая была описана выше.

Comment: А вы прекратите геокодировать. Если вам нужны координаты, читайте их из плейсмарка напрямую после перемещения. А геокодер ищет ближайший адрес каждый раз.

Comment: @YaCor' Спасибо большое! Благодаря Вам - решил проблему!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение просто - читать внимательно документацию нужно. Ну главное спасибо людям которые помогли - указали на мою невнимательность. Публикую рабочий вариант (заменил **28** и **44** строку). На будущее другим - код не будет работать т.к. apikey был отключён мной, Вам нужно будет выпустить новый apikey в личном кабинете Яндекс.

```
Адрес:
<input type="text" id="address">

Координаты:
<input type="text" id="ypoint" class="form-input">

<script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=f14114d6-4ebb-4087-b128-5d9d0454fd0e&lang&lang=ru_RU"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init() {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [46.780526, 40.862630],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

        /* Начальный адрес метки */
        var address = [46.780526, 40.862630];

        ymaps.geocode(address).then(function(res) {
            var coord = res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();

            var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(address, null, {
                preset: 'islands#blueDotIcon',
                draggable: true
            });

            /* Событие dragend - получение нового адреса */
            myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function(e){
                var cord = e.get('target').geometry.getCoordinates();
                $('#ypoint').val(cord);
                ymaps.geocode(cord).then(function(res) {
                    var data = res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.getAll();
                    $('#address').val(data.text);
                });
            });

            myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
            myMap.setCenter(address, 15);
        });
    }
</script>
```